# Retrieving the checked state of a checkbox in PHP

Tags: php

I have this line of code to send the value of checkbox to the database(1 or 0).

```
$premiere = (bool)$_POST['premiere'] == true ? 1 : 0;
```

When I check the checkbox and click save, it works. However, when I do the opposite (leaving it unchecked), I get a problem: The checkbox doesn't seem to send the "unchecked" value to the database. The code treats `$premiere` as "true" always. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the default post value of a checkbox is "on"... so maybe this helps you out.

Comment: This is PHP not JavaScript.

Comment: someone already provided you a better method but FYI problem is essentially an issue with order of operations.

Comment: I am sorry, this is php as you stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not JavaScript, your problem is between HTML and PHP.

An unchecked checkbox will not send a value to the server. You should use `isset` to check whether it is checked:

```
$premiere = isset($_POST['premiere']);
```

Also, when checking a boolean, you don't need `== true`.